# sed matching a group and the modifying the group before reusing

Tags: c, sed

I have some C code which essentially is a switch statement where MANY cases exist and most are fall through:

```
case firstCase:
case secondCase:
actionFunction(dir,angle,speed);
break;
case thirdcase:
actionFunction(dir,angle,speed);
break;
```

I have sed line `sed 's/(action.*)/if (foobar)\n\t\t\t{\n\t\t\t\t\1\n\t\t\t}else\n\t\t\t{\n\n\t\t\t\}/g'`which grabs function and places it in correct location 
    case firstCase:
    case secondCase:
    if(foobar)
    {actionFunction(dir, angle, speed);}
    else{

```
}
break;
if(foobar)
{actionFunction(dir,angle,speed);}
else{

}
```

I need to place a modified version of the match "\1" into the else clause.

```
case firstCase:
case secondCase:
if(foobar)
{actionFunction(dir, angle, speed);}
else{
actionFunction(newDir, angle, speed);
}
...
```

How do I do this?
Sorry about how long, and possibly unclear this question is!
I'm more than happy to answer what I can.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's really not clear what you want to do. Do you want to turn the switches into if /else if / else blocks? Why does you second example not use the nomenclature of the first?

Comment: `I have sed line` What sed line? `grabs function` which function? `of the match "\1"` what match? What have you tried? You may read [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and/or [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Comment: "most are fall-through" and not a single fall-through is shown... 1st and 2nd case label the *same* statement here...

Comment: sed 's/\(Drive.*\)/if (RTCMTBDriveDirection == dirForward)\n\t\t\t{\n\t\t\t\t\1\n\t\t\t}else\n\t\t\t{\n\n\t\t\t\}/g'

Comment: Basically I need to replace the one line functions starting with "Drive" with an if/else where the match is placed verbatim in the if section, and a modified function call with a difference first parameter is placed in the else clause.

Comment: You are not doing a good job of explaining what you want to achieve, I'm afraid. Can't you edit your question to include what your code looks like before and after editing? (I'm not so sure that sed is the right tool her, though.)

Comment: Does this help???

Comment: Better representation of my question:
How do I further process a group and use that processed version of the group in the substitution?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit unclear, but you might consider using [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) instead of [sed](/questions/tagged/sed):

```
awk '{print}                    # print line
     /case secondCase:/{        # if the line matches "case secondCase"
        getline                 # retrieve the next line
        print "if (foobar) {"   # print if statement
        print "   "$0           # print if action
        print "} else {         # print else statement
        sub(/dir/,"newdir")     # update action
        print "   "$0           # print else action
        print "}"               # close if-else statement
     }'
```

This outputs:

```
case firstCase:
case secondCase:
if (foobar) {
   actionFunction(dir,angle,speed);
} else {
   actionFunction(newdir,angle,speed);
}
break;
case thirdcase:
actionFunction(dir,angle,speed);
break;
```

You can adapt the above to accomodate your needs.